# Smooth Scroll Wheel - What do you use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouse

I cannot find any solution for smooth scrolling. So not to any anchor, but scrolling with a mouse for example. Anybody got a solution or tip for that? Any javascript or jquery solutions is welcome.

Thanks in advance.
Justin

Comment: Firstly plugin recommendations are off-topic for SO. Secondly, please don't do this. Smooth scrolling is terrible. All it does is hinder me from scrolling as fast as I want to, and makes me less inclined to return to your site ever again.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to apply a smooth scroll using JS, then use this working code :

```
window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
```